# Dependency injection of constants service (Error: Can't resolve all parameters for XXX ([object Object], ?).)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, constants, angular-services

I want to make constants available throughout my Angular app and I thought I would do this with a service. I keep getting this error though, seemingly no matter what I do:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StopSessionComponent: ([object
>   Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).

Below is my code at the moment, although I have tried all kinds of solutions. (I have seen a lot of similar questions, but none that have helped me.)

```
import { GlobalsService } from '../shared/globals.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stop-session',
  templateUrl: './stop-session.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../shared/forms.component.css']
})
export class StopSessionComponent implements OnInit {

  constants;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private router: Router,
    public firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private globalsService: GlobalsService,
  ) {
    this.constants = this.globalsService.getGlobals();
  }
```

globals.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GlobalsService {

  getGlobals() { return GLOBALS; }
}

export const GLOBALS = [
  { number_re: '^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$' },
];
```

I have tried adding the service to `app.module.ts` in `providers` and as an import at the top.

Comment: I guess the issue is not with the constant service, should be with other 4 services you have injected. try removing one by and see

Comment: Please check if you have imported `ReactiveFormsModule`, `RouterModule` or any other modules from which your `Injectables` are coming in. These modules should be imported in your `Feature`Module` where your component is present. Importing them in `AppModule` will not suffice. Or else create a Common module, then import all your widely used modules over there. And then import `CoreModule` elsewhere in your feature modules.

Comment: @Sajeetharan It seems to be the constant service, since everything works fine when I remove it.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Do you mean to add modules in this certain component where the error is arising? I'm using VSCode which gives an error if any module I use in the component isn't imported. I don't seem to need `ReactiveFormsModule` specifically, as I have imported `FormBuilder`, `FormGroup`, `Validators`, `FormControl`. I import `Router` and not `RouterModule`, but I guess that's equivalent?

Comment: I said, you have to import those modules in the module where your component is declared.

Comment: @AmitChigadani At the moment I only have AppModule and AppRouterModule. Everything seems to be imported in AppModule that should be, as far as I can see.